# MacBook Pro not outputting audio

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

Yesterday I could play music and actually hear something, but as of today, my MacBook Pro speakers aren't producing any sound at all.

Here is what I tried:

- rebooting (a cold reboot too) several times
- internal/external speakers
- PRAM reset
- Reinstall iTunes
- Using headphones

There is no red light in the headphone jack.

The only thing I did was updating my iTunes to the new 10.5.3 version. But I doubt this is the cause because other programs aren't reproducing any sound too. So, no sound at all on my MacBook Pro (mid 2011). Any idea or hits to get the sound back?

**EDIT**
And to make it even more weird, the mail-app is making sound when sending and receiving mails. But iTunes, QuickTime, VLC, Safari,... These apps aren't making any sound at all!

Comment: Can you listen to music using headphones? Is the red LED in the headphone jack on when there is nothing inside?

Comment: To both questions, nope...

Comment: You've double-checked to make sure that audio wasn't muted using the keyboard?

Comment: Yes, I even tripple checked it!

Comment: The audio output is set to "Internal Speakers"?

Comment: Thats not weird. They are two different sound systems. One is for Alert Sound, the other is the System Sound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first instance, please repair disk permissions. If that makes no difference please try starting your machine in [Safe Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1455) before restarting (back to normal mode) and seeing if that made any difference.

If neither of these work I would reinstall the OS over the top at this stage.

As to the cause? I think the Quicktime system plugin has incorrect permissions, is damaged or just plain isn't where it should be. Let us know how you get on!

Comment: Hurray hurray hurray! I did safe restart, rebuilding and plugging in the headphone jack. All of them a few times and finally, the sound was back! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem with my 2017 macbook pro 13" and it appears to be a common problem. The browser, sound adjustments (control panel any and all tools), etc all do not work; both through headphones and the speaker--again do not work.

the solution in the terminal is to do:

```
sudo killall coreaudiod
```

solved via google search leading to https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7768514